# Incorrect toll costs in DE

Tags: here-api

I've got some problem with calculating toll costs in DE
For example - EURO6 truck, using https://fleet.cit.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json api returns costs with 0.198 eur per km. But according to https://www.toll-collect.de/en/toll_collect/bezahlen/maut_tarife/maut_tarife.html info - tarif need to be 0.187
Where can be problem?

Example of request

https://fleet.cit.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=53.538430,9.969870;100&detail=1&waypoint1=52.369560,9.995660;100&routelegattributes=li&routeattributes=wp,sc,sh,li&maneuverattributes=none&linkattributes=none,rt,fl&legattributes=none,li,sm&tollPass=transponder,Senior_Pass&currency=EUR&departure=&tollVehicleType=3&trailerType=2&trailersCount=1&vehicleNumberAxles=2&trailerNumberAxles=3&hybrid=0&emissionType=6&fuelType=diesel&height=4m&trailerHeight=400&vehicleWeight=12000&limitedWeight=40t&disabledEquipped=0&minimalPollution=0&hov=0&passengersCount=1&tiresCount=12&commercial=1&heightAbove1stAxle=1m&width=2.55&length=16.5&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled;boatFerry:0&rollups=none,country;tollsys,country

Answer (score 0):

We could see that there are 3 warnings coming in the response. Could you please try specifying the exact values for 3 parameters as well, else it is considering the default values for the following fields and check the result. Please confirm if the result is still not correct.

```
Fields :  trailerHeight vehicleWeight length
```

Comment: Hello! checked - see answer upper

Answer (score 0):

I've checked warnings and specify these fields. No changes and still not correct result for DE tolls

https://fleet.cit.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=53.511560,10.818890;100&detail=1&waypoint1=53.536110,10.075710;100&routelegattributes=li&routeattributes=wp,sc,sh,li&maneuverattributes=none&linkattributes=none,rt,fl&legattributes=none,li,sm&tollPass=transponder,Senior_Pass&currency=EUR&departure=&tollVehicleType=3&trailerType=2&trailersCount=1&vehicleNumberAxles=2&trailerNumberAxles=3&hybrid=0&emissionType=6&fuelType=diesel&height=4m&length=18m&trailerHeight=4m&vehicleWeight=12t&limitedWeight=40t&disabledEquipped=0&minimalPollution=0&hov=0&passengersCount=1&tiresCount=12&commercial=1&heightAbove1stAxle=1m&width=2.55&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled;boatFerry:0&rollups=none,country;tollsys,country

Comment: We have raised the issue to our engineering team. will update you asap over this.